# How to determine the maximum number of levels of a tag in a document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I have a HTML document where I want to find the maximum depth of `<ol>`. Example of my question is given in [image: Picture here].

The HTML is:

```
<body>
    <nav id="abc" epub:type="abc">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="cover.xhtml">cover</a></li>
            <li><a href="review.xhtml">review</a></li>
            <li><a href="preface.xhtml">preface</a></li>
            <li><a href="ch00.xhtml">ch00</a></li>
            <li><a href="part01.xhtml">part01</a>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="ch01.xhtml">ch01</a>
                        <ol>
                            <li><a href="ch01-01.xhtml">ch01-01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ch01-02.xhtml">ch01-02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ch01-03.xhtml">ch01-03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ch01-04.xhtml">ch01-04</a></li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        <ol>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: We need to see your minimal code that demonstrates the problem otherwise it looks like you want us to write it for you, which is off-topic. Also, don't use a screen shot to provide necessary data for testing. Links to images always break resulting in questions that make no sense for others. See "[ask]" for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ol_depth = []
Nokogiri::XML::Reader(File.open('toc.xhtml')).each do |node|
  ol_depth << node.depth if node.name == 'ol'
end

ol_depth.uniq.count #=> 3
```

I used this filename because of your image.

BTW your data is wrong (last `</ol>` without slash)

Comment: This doesn't really take advantage of the strengths Nokogiri brings to code because it's only iterating through the document's nodes. In a big document it'd be inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is really HTML, not XML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML html_string
doc.search('ol').map{|ol| ol.ancestors('ol').length}.max
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

On a quick glance, it looks like this'd do what you want:

```
html = <<~EOT
  <body>
      <ol>
          <li><a href="cover.xhtml">cover</a></li>
              <ol>
                  <li><a href="ch01.xhtml">ch01</a>
                      <ol>
                          <li><a href="ch01-01.xhtml">ch01-01</a></li>
                      </ol>
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </li>
      </ol>
  </body>
EOT

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
ol_depth = doc.at('ol') ? doc.search('ol ol').size + 1 : 0
ol_depth # => 3
```

It's taking advantage of CSS being able to find tags within tags via `ol ol`. If `at('ol')` finds an `ol` node it'll return it triggering a more in-depth search for all the other nested nodes.

This'll break down if there are multiple sections in the document containing nested `ol` tags though. I suspect the other answers have the same problem but didn't test them.